# How to detect a Long press in a game with flutter/flame

Tags: flutter, flame

I have a rect appearing in the game and I am able to detect taps like this

in main.dart

```
TapGestureRecognizer tapper = TapGestureRecognizer();
tapper.onTapDown = game.onTapDown;
flameUtil.addGestureRecognizer(tapper);
```

in game-controller.dart

```
void onTapDown(TapDownDetails d) {
  if (mainMenu.tutorialBtnRect.contains(d.globalPosition)) {
   mainMenu.tutorialTapped();
  }
}
```

I can't seem to be able to get it to work with any of the LongPressGestures
Something about PrimaryButton and velocity I am not able to set

Please help

Thanks

Comment: You can use 'LongPressDetector' mixin in your game class which extends 'Game' from flame.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to not use the GestureRecognizers and just implement it directly on your game.

```
class MyGame extends BaseGame with LongPressDetector {

  MyGame();

  @override
  void onLongPressEnd(LongPressEndDetails details) {
    if (mainMenu.tutorialBtnRect.contains(details.globalPosition)) {
      mainMenu.tutorialTapped();
    }
  }
}
```